# Does Trox Grappling Appendages stack damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, racial-traits

I am in a campaign with a trox brawler and am wondering about clarification for the trox ability grabbing appendages. If the trox can maintain grapple and still make an attack roll, does that mean that he can do the ability such as damage, move, or pin etc. that is included in the action to maintain grappling and also make an attack roll, or does making the attack roll allowed by the appendage ability mean that they can't do the damage, move, pin etc. and only get to maintain grapple and attack. If that's the case, then why does it matter that the trox gets to make an attack while maintaining grapple if they can already deal damage during the grapple instead of risking missing with an attack?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Adam, take the [tour] when you have a moment, and browse the [help] when you have two or three moments for a more detailed look and how the site works.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142853/8610).

Answer (score 2):

### Grabbing Appendages just gives you options

Grabbing Appendages has an unfortunate amount of fluff with very specific mechanical effects:

- You have Improved Graple at level 1
- You can use both hands while Grappling

At early levels, this just saves you from Attacks of Opportunity to Grapple (or the feat cost of Improved Grapple). However, if you choose to *lean into* this aspect of Troxs' abilities, you will eventually have [Greater Grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-grapple-combat/) and potentially [Rapid Grappler](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-grappler-combat/). *That* is when the second feature becomes interesting. You now have the ability to maintain a Grapple as a Move action and still swing a two-handed weapon around* or do other things that require both hands or a free hand while you have a weapon out like moving them while climbing.

*Technically you could swing two weapons around, but that's its own feat-intensive plan and generally doesn't work because you [don't seem to be able to initiate Grapples with your hands full](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142853/28326).